# How to pass data without the use of a segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Recently I have been making a app where you can create and quiz yourself on definitions or anything for that matter.  I pass data to the next view after it the user hits the create button to make the title of the new notecard.  The code I am using right now for that is:

```
 override  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

let DestViewController: Card1 = segue.destinationViewController as! Card1

DestViewController.Content = Notetitle.text!


self.saved = self.Notetitle.text!


}
```

All of that works but, it will only work if I have a segue between `viewcontrollers`.  I need to be able to pass that data with out a segue because I want the user to be able to create as many notecards as they want and the way I am trying to do that now is by using this code to make a copy of the `UIView` and then put in the new data (a master view).  The new view can only be create using an `IBAction`.  The prepare for segue I cannot use in the `IBAction` because it is it's own override function.

This is the code I am using to make a the new view:

```
let newCard =
    self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main")

self.presentViewController(newCard, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

My hope is that I will be able to make a new view and then pass in the data pass in the data that the user just made to go on the notecard.  (Hope this makes any sense at all)

MAIN TOPICS:
-Create a new view and pass in new data 
    Problem: Can pass data without a segue dont have one :/
-Be able to pass data between view controllers without a segue :)

I am new to all of this about 5 months.  All of my code is in swift.  Take it easy on me please. Feel free to ask me with any questions or comments.

Thanks,
 Lucas Mazza

Comment: Instead of instantiating a new view controller for every new "card," why not design the app so that there is just one view controller (say, "CardViewController") that can be reused for every card. When a user wants to change cards you can animate the view to make it seem like it's changing, even though behind the scenes it's just one controller. Just a thought.

Comment: Thats a great idea thanks for the idea will try it out @gmat1014

Comment: @matt Any suggestions?

Comment: @Duncan C any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I think it will help you.

```
let newCard =
self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as? DestViewController
newCard.Content = Notetitle.text!
self.presentViewController(newCard!, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: I get an error under DestViewController: us of undeclared type 'DestViewController' @Paruru

Comment: I think the error is coming from not having a segue.  Which I did want but it still needs to work.

Comment: Could someone else help me out

Comment: @MazzaMan I have a misstake for type conversion, "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" return a UIViewController, but we need DestViewController, so use  'as?' to convert it. See my edit answer. BTW, If I do this work, I will make a segue of controller to controller, not use IBAction, so whenever you want show  DestViewController,  just call the method performThe Segue "performSegueWithIdentifier".